# no acces to .txt with Webmatrix ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix

I got a tiny website for my company to check in which store a brand can be found.
The website uses a c# code to check .txt files in a subfolder.
It worked nice while I used a path like "C:\brands" on my pc but now I try to host the homepage so I changed the path to "~/App_Data/Brands/Normal" + StoreNames()[i] + ".txt".
But now I can't access the .txt files anymore.
The txt files are located in root/App_Data/Brands/Normal but the code is in root/App_Code. Could that be a problem?

Also I'm trying to access the files without any special permissions or an account.
The host is https://panel.sitecloud.cytanium.com/.

What do I need to get access to the files again?
It could be a problem with my code too because it doesn't work on localhost either (where it worked with an extern folder)..

Edit:

Okay, MapPath did the job! I just forgot to add MapPath also to
if(File.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(sFilename)))..

Comment: Can you show the page that displays the output? It appears like you are trying to access App_Code or App_Data in your browser.

Comment: How are you trying to access the data in your browser? You can change the domain name for security purposes.

Comment: I added the Default.cshtml code and added the link to the homepage in the comments under your awnser.
Have to go now but I will check later again.
Thank you already for so much effort to help me! :-)
I need it for my application tommorrow.. :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath` to get the physical directory:

```
string data = File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/TextFile.txt"));
```

Comment: I added the part where the file is read..
How do i need to change that to work with MapPath? I Just get errors when I try something like sContent = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(sFilename));.. (in this case it says the name "Server" does not exist..

Comment: Okay found it in a other question. Now I use HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath with "using System.Web".

It seems to work (no errors occure on runtime) but I still can't access the files...

Comment: Sorry, I forgot you're working with .cs in your App_Code. I'll update my answer.

Comment: What do you mean you cannot access the files? You're not getting output or?

Comment: Hmm when trying to open the folder with the files from Webmatrix in browser it says paths included in "hiddenSegment" are rejected and I should check "configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/hiddenSegments" in the data "applicationhost.config" or "web.config".

Could that be the solution? Where can I find those data?
Its hard to explain the error because I use the german version so the error is in german too..

Comment: You're not trying to access the file using browser, are you? Perhaps you can explain how your site works. For example: 1) user visits the page 2) the page reads the file and prints text. Or you can show some codes.

Comment: I mean it seems like the script can't access the files because it should check the .txt files if the brand name, which was chosen in a drop-down menu, is included in a specific file and go through all files. I know that a brand is included in many of the files but the script returns "the brand is currently not available in any of our stores" (free translation by myself).
Also I know that when I was using a extern directory (my dropbox) it worked finde and the script returned something like "this brand is available in Berlin, Hamburg and other german cities"..

Comment: I will add the complete script to the question but it's only commented in german. I hope it's not to confusing..

Comment: You can check it our here:
http://kiki-markenfinder.sitecloud.cytanium.com/

It's in german but I think it explains itself.
You just choose the brand you want and it SHOULD return the stores..

Comment: Are you sure the text files contain the data they should have? If reading the text file is already achieved, I think your question has been answered. Sorry, I could not help you any longer, need to go. :/

Comment: The textfiles contain 100% what they should. Already checked them to be sure. Thank you anyway for your efforts! :)

Comment: MapPath did the job!
I forgot to add it also to if(File.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(sFilename))) so the files were never read.. Thank you really much! :-)